# Select the rows with lowest value in specific column from those who match the other critarias

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have created an SQL table to save events data into it.

Each event can have multiple occurrences and when I filter them on site - I want to have the first matching occurrence of each event. each occurrence is saved in a different row, which contains a column for the general event_id and specific occ_id to each occurrence.

I need to get from the matching rows - only one row from each event_id, and it needs to be the one with the lowest occ_id value.

i.e.

```
gen_id  | event_id | occ_id | month
------------------------------------
1       | 190      | 1      | 4    
2       | 190      | 2      | 4    
3       | 190      | 3      | 4    
4       | 192      | 1      | 4    
5       | 192      | 2      | 4    
6       | 192      | 3      | 4    
7       | 193      | 1      | 5    
8       | 193      | 2      | 5
```

If I'm looking for events from month = 4, I need to get the events (gen_id): 1,4

and if I'm looking for month = 5 I need to get only event (gen_id): 7

My SQL query right now gets the matching events but with no occ_id filteration:

(it looks something like this right now)

```
SELECT
    event_id,
    event_title,
    occ_id
    FROM
    table_name
    WHERE month = 4
    GROUP BY event_id
    ORDER BY
    event_id
    DESC
```

I have tried to also use MIN / MAX but I guess it either not the right handler for this case or I'm using it wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to filter.  One method uses a correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select t.*
from table_name t
where t.occ_id = (select min(t2.occ_id)
                  from table_name t2
                  where t2.event_id = t.event_id
                 );
```

However, the lowest value always seems to be "1", so this might work as well:

```
select t.*
from table_name t
where t.month = 4 and
      t.occ_id = 1;
```

To add `month`, you can add it to the outer query:

```
select t.*
from table_name t
where t.month = 4 and
      t.occ_id = (select min(t2.occ_id)
                  from table_name t2
                  where t2.event_id = t.event_id and
                        t2.month = t.month
                 );
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!
Think I'm getting the subquery thing better now too.

Comment: The lowest occ_id won't always be 1.
If an event is occurring in months 4 and 5 for example and twice each month, and I'm filtering by month '5' - the lowest occ_id in this case will probably be 3...

Answer (score 0):

umm,

```
select t.event_id, t.occ_id, t.month, min(t.gen_id) from (
    select event_id,month,min(occ_id) as min_occ_id from t where month=5 group by event_id, month
) t1 join t on t1.min_occ_id = t.occ_id and t1.event_id = t.event_id and t1.month = t.month
group by t.event_id, t.occ_id, t.month;
```

if columns `event_id`,`occ_id`,`month` make up an UNIQUE KEY, the SQL can be simplified.

```
select t.event_id, t.occ_id, t.month, t.gen_id from (
    select event_id,month,min(occ_id) as min_occ_id from t where month=5 group by event_id, month
) t1 join t on t1.min_occ_id = t.occ_id and t1.event_id = t.event_id and t1.month = t.month
```